# tests fail when building Go from source

Tags: go

I cannot pass build tests when I build Golang from source:

```
hg clone -u release https://code.google.com/p/go
cd go/src
./all.bash

....
ok      net/url 0.005s
ok      os  0.595s
--- FAIL: TestExtraFiles (0.12 seconds)
exec_test.go:230: TestExtraFiles: Something already leaked - closed fd 3
exec_test.go:403: Run: exit status 1; stdout "leaked parent file. fd = 10; want 9\n", stderr ""
FAIL
FAIL    os/exec 0.822s
ok      os/signal   0.511s
```

please help. this is on my webfaction shared machine.

```
[~] lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 5.10 (Final)
Release:    5.10
Codename:   Final
```

Comment: Which OS and what kernel version?

Comment: I have updated the question with this info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in CentOS 5/RHEL 5 according to [issue 3001](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=3001), basicly the kernel ignores `O_CLOEXEC`.

So either ignore the error (bad idea) or move to a more recent Linux version.

Comment: Actually it should be fully working, you will get random crashes with cgo but it should be there. do you have `$GOROOT/bin` in your `$PATH`?